Выбор знака препинания в прямой речи
Какой знак препинания вы выберите в этом предложении перед кавычками и после?
«Давайте возьмём зефир и пожарим его прямо на огне...»... предложила моя младшая сестра, главная сладкоежка семьи.

У Розенталя есть вариант:  «Я хотел бы купить крестьян…»  — сказал Чичиков, запнулся и не кончил речи (Г.).

Я не отрицаю выбор многоточия. Но это предложение взято из учебника Грамоты ру. И там неоднозначный вариант.

Серж, а в этой позиции может быть один из трех знаков: вопросит.,  восклицат, и многоточие, а точка меняется на запятую после кавычек. Я поставила вопросит. знак, вроде правильно.  https://gramota.ru/uchebnik/uprazhneniya/pryamaya-rech

Запятую и тире посчитали за ошибку. А восклицательного знака там и не было.

Восклицательного знака там не было. Что странно.

И даже в этом предложении некорректное оформление.
«А вот здесь, где жители замка хранили продукты, в основном мясо и овощи,—увлечённо рассказывал гид
. —
из-за камня сохранялся подходящий температурный режим, так что запасы не портились».

Почему-то после точки строчная. Прописную посчитали за ошибку.

Там ведь сложное предложение еще не кончилось, продолжается после слов автора. Слова автора с двух сторон выделятся запятой и тире.

Там именно такое оформление.

«Давайте возьмём зефир и пожарим его прямо на огне...» — предложила моя младшая сестра, главная сладкоежка семьи.

А зачем многоточие?
